# VPN connection between 2 google instances across google project

Tags: google-compute-engine, vpn

We have a technical requirement, wherein we need to have two instances across different google project (but under same google account) to communicate with each other.

To illustrate, we have two google project X and Y under the same google account. We need all our VM instance on project X (of google account) to have a reliable communication(maybe over HTTP) with a known VM instance of project Y(of the same google account).

Because we programmatically scale up and scale down our VM instances of project X we cannot approach the solution of whitelisting IPs of VM instances of X on Project Y firewall. (under google networking rule)

We have been reading around [VPN in google](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/creating-vpns),(sure and easier solution to this could be a Proxy but because of our business constraints, we cannot explore that as possible options).

Google documentation says about VPN setup of two kind **static** and **dynamic** route.

But, because of our limited experience(never set the VPN before) on this we are not sure what is the ideal VPN setup(or there exist any other solution which we haven't encountered yet) for us.

Can some one please help with some pointer on the correct setup for above problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VPN to connect your two projects. Both static or dyanmic will work. Dynamic requires you to set up Cloud Routers in both projects and some additional configuration and allows your network to automatically react if the VPN is down. However I don't think this is helpful for you as you don't have a fallback, so static VPN is probably the better choice for you.

You may also want to look at [VPC Network Peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering) and [Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc). These allow instacnes in different projects to communicate without needing a VPN at all.